# Gradle task: forcing javaCompile before task execution

Tags: java, gradle

I am currently migrating our ant tasks over to gradle and have run into an issue. I have a task called **copy_data** which I need to execute after a build. The current way I have it set up is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/java'
    main.resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

repositories {
    // All my repos
}

dependencies {
    // All my dependencies
}

task copy_data(dependsOn: compileJava){
    doLast{
        copy{
            from "${base_data_dir}"
            into "${data_dir}"
            exclude('build/', 'build/**')
            includeEmptyDirs = false 
        }
        // various other copies etc.
    }
}
```

For some reason it throws the following error

> Execution failed for task ':copy_data'.
>   build_8a9r4tsfqjq9meq9akmu6803e$_run_closure5$_closure29$_closure30

Now sometimes it works fine but it is not consistent.  If I omit the **dependsOn: compileJava**, manually delete the cache and build dir and run **gradle build** before I run **gradle copy_data** it never throws the error.

I am new to gradle so any suggestions where I could make this a little more consistent would be great.

Comment: maybe you can add extra delete directory for your `clean` task, `clean {
    delete 'someFile'
}`? I dont know how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yea it's weird.  I can't consistently reproduce it either, though it's happening right now as I type.  Here is the message 

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\edunn\eclipse-workspace\iC\build.gradle' line: 201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':copy_data'.
> build_8a9r4tsfqjq9meq9akmu6803e$_run_closure5$_closure30$_closure31

Comment: it seems you have extra `$_cl‌​osure31` this time?

Comment: I can fix it if I kill the java daemon and re run it but I'd like to find a better solution